# Can I plot a percentage of subcategory in ggplot without summarizing a long format data table?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-manipulation

I wish to plot "percentage positivity" in the following dataset using ggplot, and am wondering if I can do so without modifying the dataset.

`Percentage Positivity = Pos / (Pos + Neg)`

Code to generate dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(0)

df <- tibble(Result = c(rep("Pos", 6), rep("Neg",6)),
             Group1 = rep(1:6, 2), Group2 = rep(1:3, 4), Value = rnorm(12, 5, 2))

# A tibble: 12 x 4
   Result Group1 Group2 Value
   <chr>   <int>  <int> <dbl>
 1 Pos         1      1  7.53
 2 Pos         2      2  4.35
 3 Pos         3      3  7.66
 4 Pos         4      1  7.54
 5 Pos         5      2  5.83
 6 Pos         6      3  1.92
 7 Neg         1      1  3.14
 8 Neg         2      2  4.41
 9 Neg         3      3  4.99
10 Neg         4      1  9.81
11 Neg         5      2  6.53
12 Neg         6      3  3.40
```

Ignoring Group2, the positivity for Group1 = 1 for example would be `7.53/(7.53 + 3.14)`.

I'm mostly a PowerBI user, and am new to R, so the kind of code I have in mind is something like:

```
plot <- ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_col(aes(x = Group1, y = Value[where result = pos]/Value[where result = pos + neg))
```

I don't really want to calculate the percentage positivity by summarizing Group1 and creating a new calculated column, because in my actual dataset, I have many variables and datetime hierarchies, and need to calculate percentage positivity by slicing the dataset in a large number of ways. So I'm thinking I shouldn't have to create a new dataframe for every single way I think of slicing the data.

Is there any way to do what I ask?

Happy to hear the opinions of more experienced users on modelling/visualization best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it will be the exact answer you are looking for, but "without" creating a new dataset, you can create a pipe sequence that will calculate proportions as you wish and pass it into `ggplot`.

Like that, you can "slice" your data in all possible ways you are thinking of without modifying the original `df`.

Here, for your example, you can do the following:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% group_by(Group1) %>%
  mutate(Value2 = Value / sum(Value)) %>%
  filter(Result == "Pos") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Group1), y = Value2))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(Value2)), vjust = -0.5)
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: yes I think it is, at least for this example. Thank you very much. I think I needed to see the group_by concept; hopefully I can now apply it to the actual datasets I'm working with.

Comment: You're welcome ;). Here the official documentation for `group_by` https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by.html.